# Android browser/Dolphin - CSS rotation

Tags: css, android-browser

I am trying to rotate an element using CSS.  It works in most of the browsers, but I'm having an issue in Dolphin/Android browser:

```
transform: rotate(-90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

What do I need to rotate it in Dolphin/Android browser?

Comment: Android browsers only support around 63% of CSS3, Dolphin supports less

Comment: It looks like [**it is supported**](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform) with the `-webkit-` prefix as you already have. What exactly is the problem?